# DNS Not Updating on Ubuntu (Using VPN)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

Yesterday I updated the DNS for an internet domain name. 24 hours later, despite all other services and computer routing to the new configuration. My Ubuntu install still sending me to the old DNS configuration. I've tried clearing all the various caches, restarting etc. but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever DNS server your Ubuntu is pointing at (in /etc/resolv.conf) probably still has (or had) the old entry cached.  If you forget to drop the TTL at least one TTL-long period before you make a change, you'll run afoul of this.  E.g., if your original entry has a TTL of 1 day, that means it can be cached for 1 day and if you change it right after some remote server has asked about it, it will be 1 day before that server comes back to get the new answer.

It is very common to cause this as a matter of course, because you will have made a connection to the site at the old address right before you changed it.

Check what your TTL was set to and that'll be the max timeframe (from the time you change it) until it will *really* be visible everywhere.

And in the future, plan ahead for this.  It's really difficult to get every DNS server's cache cleared across the Internet (there are millions).